# How to configure QoS on home router

Tags: router, qos

I have a [USR9105](http://www.usr.com/support/product-template.asp?prod=9105) router and I'd like to configure its QoS to prioritize web traffic (browser) over everything else (e.g. torrents). I'm confused by its interface though:

[image]

"IP precedence" allows selecting a number from 0 to 7, while "IP type of service" can be one of "Normal Service", "Minimize cost", "Maximize reliability", "Maximize throughput" and "Minimize delay".

How should I set it up? Is QoS the wrong solution to avoiding torrents slowing down browsing to a crawl? Should I set up a proxy and traffic shaping instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets look at all the fields, setting up for high priority browser traffic...

**Traffic Class Name** [set to anything you want]

**Priority** [set to high]

**IP Precedence** [I think you can leave this at 0]

**IP Type Of Service** [I think you can leave this at Normal Service]

**Protocol** [Leave this as TCP/UDP]

**Source IP Address** [Leave this blank]

**Source Subnet Mask** [Leave this blank]

**Source Port** [Leave this blank]

**Destination IP Address** [Leave this blank]

**Destination Subnet Mask** [Leave this blank]

**Destination Port** [You need to account for port 80 and port 8080 so type `80:8080`]

I believe this will work for you as long as you are allowed to leave the fields blank that I said to leave blank.  Hopefully you will not need to make a similar class for torrents, if you do then that class should be set to low priority.