# How to set up QoS on ADSL router (terracom) for prioritizing browsing

Tags: router, qos

I want to configure the ADSL router which connects 10+ machines to the internet. I want to give maximum priority to browsing (ports 80,443) and set low priority for bittorrent etc.(port 42180)

I have been experimenting with settings , but with no luck. There are three settings which confuse me, along with my understanding.

[image]

1. 802.1 Priority - Related to LAN level, possible values 0-7 , higher numbers means higher priority.
2. 'Mark traffic priority' - clueless about this.
3. IPP/DS -  IP Precedence - possible values 0-7 ; 6 & 7 are reserved, so set 5 for highest priority. Or when using DSCP - set 46 for highest priority.

Please help me in getting this done.

Similer question for another model of router here , but with less number of confusing options :) [How to configure QoS on home router](https://superuser.com/questions/225453/how-to-configure-qos-on-home-router)

Comment: Remember that you can only prioritise outgoing traffic.

Comment: i also had the same question in mind.it had 'upstream traffic' in that config page. Atleast can we control traffic inside the subnet, ie prioritizing the packets to/from some specific port, so that it makes a diffference?

Comment: Will flashing the router with DD-WRT or tomato help to make the desired changes?

Comment: I have not used DD-WRT very much.  I use Tomato, as it is said that the QoS is easier to set up and works better than it does on DD-WRT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First of all by Qos you can only control outgoing trafic**. Limiting outgoing traffic in turn may have an effect on incoming traffic on that port.

My ADSL router Qos page starts something like below

[image]

As you can see you need to provide source IP address i.e your IP address to which a priority is set(P0 is highest).

Now if you want to add new rules to Qos it goes something like below

[image]

As you can see the minimum requirement for adding a rule entry to Qos is the source IP address. Of course you can provide other configs like dest port/IP or src IP and the corresponding priority.